# ¿Cómo buscar datos dentro de un archivo alojado en un servidor web?

Tags: java, netbeans, buscador

Necesito buscar hasta 3 palabras, separadas por `;` dentro de varios archivos que se encuentran en un servidor web.

Código:

```
package prueba.de.buscar.dentro.de.un.archivo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PruebaDeBuscarDentroDeUnArchivo {
    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        java.util.Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce una cadena de texto a buscar: ");
        String request = scanner.next();
        try {
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:\\Users\\ProKode\\Downloads\\archivo.txt")
            );
            String line = "";    
            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                if(line.indexOf(";")!= -1){
                    if (line.split(";")[0].equalsIgnoreCase(request)) {
                        System.out.println("Se encontro la palabra "+ request);
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException           e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Pero me sale este error:

> Exception in thread `main` `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`: 0
>
> at `prueba.de.buscar.dentro.de.un.archivo.PruebaDeBuscarDentroDeUnArchivo.main(PruebaDeBuscarDentroDeUnArchivo.java:23`)
>
> Java Result: 1
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)

Esta es la linea 23:

```
if(line.indexOf(";") != -1)
```

El contenido del archivo es (es un ejemplo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Salida:

> Introduce una cadena de texto a buscar:
>
> moises;diego;usuario
>
> Se encontro la palabra: moises.
>
> Se encontro la palabra: diego.
>
> Se encontro la palabra: usuario.

NOTA: LAS MAYUSCULAS NO IMPORTAN.

Comment: Esta pregunta [estába cerrada](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58223/como-hacer-una-busqueda-en-java-web) y en proceso de reapertura ... no hacia falta que la eliminaras ....

Comment: Puedes marcar exactamente la línea 23 en este código? El problema no puede ser el indice 0 despues del `split`, porque después de hacer un `split` **siempre** tienes un arreglo de mínimo tamaño 1.

Comment: Te dejé código de prueba en una respuesta. Por lo menos debería cambiar la Excepción con eso, espero que eso nos da una pista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te debería salir un `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` en la línea indicada, porque en esta linea no hay ningún método que podría tirar una.

Si cambias este código:

```
        while((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            if(line.indexOf(";")!= -1){
                if (line.split(";")[0].equalsIgnoreCase(request)) {
                    System.out.println("Se encontro la palabra "+ request);
                }
            }
        }
```

por

```
        while((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            String token0 = line.split(";",-1)[0]; // agrega el limite
            if (token0.equalsIgnoreCase(request)) {
                System.out.println("Se encontro la palabra "+ request);
            }
         }
```

te debería salir un arreglo de tamaño > 0 seguramente.

En la búsqueda con `split`, un limite *n > 0* limita la cantidad de los resultados a *n*, un limite de *n=-1* te da todos los resultados posibles con un minimo del String entero si no se encuentra el patrón. *n=0* se comporta como *n=-1* con la diferencia que cadenas al fin se descartan.

Por ahora no logro de reproducir una `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` con ninguna de las líneas de código en la parte indicada, usando permutaciónes de String sin ";" incluso "".

Viendo que no puedo reconstruir el error, usemos código más seguro:

```
        while((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            System.out.println(String.format("in> \"%s\"",line));
            String[] token = line.split(";",-1); // agrega el limite
            if (token.length>0 && token[0].equalsIgnoreCase(request)) {
                System.out.println("Se encontro la palabra "+ request);
            }
         }
```

Para la busqueda de la palabra en hasta 3 palabras separados por ";" usas:

```
        while((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            System.out.println(String.format("in> \"%s\"",line));
            String[] token = line.split(";",-1); // agrega el limite
            int len = Math.min(token.length, 3); // max 3 palabras
            for (int i = 0; i<len;i++){
                if (token[i].equalsIgnoreCase(request)) {
                    System.out.println("Se encontro la palabra "+ request);
                }
            }
         }
```

**Actualización**

Con la actualisación de la pregunta con clarificación que se busca se cambia un poco el código necesario:

```
package prueba.de.buscar.dentro.de.un.archivo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PruebaDeBuscarDentroDeUnArchivo {
    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        java.util.Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce una cadena de texto a buscar: ");
        String request = scanner.next();
        // aquí tenemos que extraer hasta tres palabras que hay que buscar
        // en cada línea del archivo
        // se coloca un limite de 4 para luego considerar max 3 resultados
        // en caso de 3 ";" el resto de la entrada se encuentra en busqueda[3]
        String[] busqueda = request.split(";",4);
        try {
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:\\Users\\ProKode\\Downloads\\archivo.txt")
            );
            String line = "";
            int len = Math.min(busqueda.length,3); // busquemos max 3 palabras
            // convertimos las palabras de busqueda a mínusculas para permitir busqueda ignorando "case"
            for (int i = 0, i < len; i++){ busqueda[i] = busqueda[i].toLowerCase().trim(); }   
            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                // aquí tenemos que buscar las palabras en un bucle
                for (int i = 0 ; i < len; i++)            
                    int pos = line.toLowerCase().indexOf(busqueda[i]);
                    if (pos > -1) {
                        System.out.println("Se encontro la palabra "+
                            line.substring(pos,pos + busqueda[i].length()));
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException           e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Implementé la solución usando los métodos que tu también usaste (`split` y `indexOf`). Existía una alternativa de procesar las líneas de tu archivo con una expresión regular usando `Pattern` y un `Matcher` que sería un poco más elegante (basado en opiniones).

Comment: Hola amigo @StefanNodes sigue diciendo el mismo error pero ahora dice que se encuentra aqui `String token0 = line.split(";")[0];`

Comment: Ok, puedes agregar un `System.out.println(line.length)` antes del split y decirme que es tu target version? (Java6,Java7...)?

Comment: Tengo java 7 amigo

Comment: Ya lo agregue antes del split y esta leyendo linea por linea, muestra la contidad de los caracters por linea

Comment: Te resulta ahora? El limite (en el caso de -1 explicitamente sin limite) es el limite de iteraciones en la busqueda por el ";". limite 0 significaría sin limite de busqueda, botando strings vacios al fin. Un limite positivo limitaría la busqueda a un resultado de 3 elementos.

Comment: Amigo si dejo el codigo asi:   `String token0 = line.split(";",-1)[0];` no muestra nada

Comment: pero tampoco una excepción?

Comment: nada amigo ni siquiera na excpción

Comment: Me entra la sospecha que la causa porque no puedo reproducir el error es por el archivo. Añadí un System.out, agregalo y comparte la salida.

Comment: Vale amigo espera un momento y hago unas pruebas vale

Comment: Bueno amigos ya hice las pruebas al momento de buscar 1 palabra sale bien, pero al buscar 2 o 3 no sale nada

Comment: Por supuesto, porque por ahora solamente busquemos la primera palabra para deshacernos de la excepción. Te agrego código para la búsqueda de hasta 3 palabras

Comment: solo busca 1 solo aun amigo

Comment: Como he dicho, si puedes aclarar un poco más preciso que exactamente buscas en que y compartes el contenido del archivo (o la salida por stdout) se puede arreglar el código para hacer preciso lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Gracias amigo te o agradezco mucho!!!!!!!! 
Problema RESUELTO.

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que sería más fácil si buscas directamente las palabras en cada linea. En lugar de:

```
if(line.indexOf(";")!= -1){                
    if (line.split(";")[0].equalsIgnoreCase(request)) {                 
        System.out.println("Se encontro la palabra "+ request);                    
    }
}
```

Prueba esto:

```
String words = word1 + ";" + word2 + ";" + word3;
if(line.indexOf(words) > -1){                
    System.out.println("Se encontro la palabra "+ request);                    
}
```

Comment: Hola amigo @FernandoForcén gracias por tu respuesta lo intentare

Comment: Eso funciona solamente si la línea contiene las tres palabras separados por ";" en la misma secuencia, y no ignora el "case".

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` significa que has intentado acceder a una posición de un array que no existe (un número negativo, o un número mayor que el tamaño del array - 1<sup>*</sup>)

El índice al que has intentado acceder es `0`, lo cual significa que el array no tiene ningún elemento (`line.split(";").length == 0`). Esto pasa porque la línea simplemente no tiene ningún ";" (posiblemente sea que tienes una línea en blanco al final del archivo).

Lo más normal sería comprobar esas condiciones; por ejemplo.

- Que no sea una línea en blanco (`!line.trim().isEmpty()`) antes de hacer el split.
- Guardar el resultado del split en un array `String[] palabras = line.split(";");` y comprobar su tamaño (`palabras.length > 0`) antes de intentar acceder al elemento 0.

En ambos casos, deberías decidir cómo se comportará el programa: puedes simplemente ignorar la línea o informar al usuario de un error de ejecución ("Se ha encontrado una línea sin ';', el contenido de la línea es " + line).

---

<sup>*</sup>Como en C, los índices del array empiezan por el 0, con lo cual los valores válidos van desde `0` hasta `[tamaño del array - 1]`.

Comment: En Java, String.split()` no funciona así. Incluso con un String de tamaño 0 te devuelve un arreglo de mínimo tamaño 1 (el elemento en indice 0 siendo el string original).